# From nine to thirty-two, who are the members of this list?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Ordered from nine to thirty-two,
Your job now's to find out who:
Who are the members of this list?
Try again if your guess you missed.

Sixteen, twenty, twenty-five, thirty-five
Didn't leave their posts alive.
Nor did twelve or twenty-nine,
But their ends were far more fine.

Thirty-seven fell from grace,
The only one to leave his place.
Now play your cards well,
And us all the answer tell.

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to connect 35 and 37 to a list from nine to thirty-two..

Comment: @Bass It's not a mistake in the puzzle.

Comment: I thouhgt it might be puzzling users ids, and thought I had it when user 37 came up with page not found, but the rest all seem to be there.

Answer (score 17):

The numbers seem to correspond to

> [US presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States) that didn't finish their term.

In particular, the mentioned numbers are

> Presidents that died while in office:
>  9: William Henry Harrison
>  12: Zachary Taylor
>  16: Abraham Lincoln
>  20: James A. Garfield
>  25: William McKinley
>  29: Warren G. Harding
>  32: Franklin D. Roosevelt
>  35: John F. Kennedy

except 37, which is

> Nixon, the only one who resigned.

Comment: That's pretty much it. I meant the solution to be all 40+ members of the list you refer to, but it's true that most of the clues refer specifically to ones who suffered the fate you refer to.

Comment: Also, why "from nine to thirty-two"?

Comment: 9 and 32 are those who served shortest and longest time, respectively, if that has any relevance.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl oh wow, I thought it was just that they were the only two of that particular fate that weren’t mentioned elsewhere in the text.

Comment: Rand, you gonna accept?

Comment: @North All in good time. (Also, this answer isn't quite complete without incorporating Carl's comment.)

Comment: Oh, also, there's a clue you missed in the last few lines.

Comment: There's a card game named 'presidents', I'm fairly certain that's what the last 2 lines refer to.

Comment: "Sixteen, twenty, twenty-five, thirty-five" are the ones who were assassinated.

Comment: @Riker Nope, I'd never heard of that game.

Comment: @Randal'Thor To dig this one up from long ago, is the missing clue from the last few lines [POT + US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States) ('play your cards well' to win the jackPOT + 'us' mentioned directly in the text)?

Comment: @Stiv I honestly can't remember; that does make some sense, but I don't think it's what I had in mind. Oh, actually I think I got it: the cards thing was referring to the then-current US president, whose name might be used to win a game of cards. Maybe the puzzle didn't age so well :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ha! Okay, that makes sense. Just spotted this one while passing through - the perils of linked questions in the sidebar...! :)