# The twenty-third is four-six

Tags: riddle, knowledge

[So, I really liked this riddle, so this is based off this one here.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62630/from-nine-to-thirty-two-who-are-the-members-of-this-list)

> The first is actually seventy-six
>
> The tenth is actually seventy-five
>
> The sixteenth is actually seventy-eight
>
> The eighteenth is actually seventy-nine
>
> IT DOESN’T MAKE SENSE!

Comment: Is "four-six" (instead of "forty-six") intentional in the title?

Comment: Are we supposed to solve an actual problem/question, or can we just agree with the riddle that "IT DOESN'T MAKE SENSE!" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is

> The Prime Ministers of Canada by age

The first is actually seventy-six

> John A. Macdonald lived 76 years

The tenth is actually seventy-five

> W. L. Mackenzie King lived 75 years

The sixteenth is actually seventy-eight

> Joe Clark is 78 years old.

The eighteenth is actually seventy-nine

> Brian Mulroney is 79 years old.

And the title:
The twenty-third is four-six

> Justin Trudeau is 46 years old.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you get to the conclusion that these are the Prime Ministers of Canada by age?

Comment: The riddle you linked to was about US Presidents, so I figured you might have constructed this riddle around the leaders of a different country. And to say that someone "is 76" means that that's their age.