# Many have become me, many more desire to be me

Tags: riddle, history

For the past centuries, many have been me. Many more desire to become me. Some are forgotten, others are remembered.

At first I became a whole city; later on I've been a neighbor, a teddy bear, a shrub and a field of roses. I've been a fat cat that likes lasagna, another time I've been a grant. I've been the son of John, and I've also been a car brand.

Now I've become the notion that I display my superiority over others, which many others considered true of me anyway since the very beginning.

Comment: [Related riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62630/5373) :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> President of the United States of America.

*For the past centuries, many have been me. Many more desire to become me. Some are forgotten, others are remembered.*

> In all, since the 18th century there have been 45 US Presidents (including Grover Cleveland's non-concurrent terms separately). A lot of people want to be the President - it's an aspiration. And while you may find it easy to name a few Presidents, it'll probably work out quite hard to name them all...

*At first I became a whole city; later on I've been a neighbor, a teddy bear, a shrub and a field of roses. I've been a fat cat that likes lasagna, another time I've been a grant. I've been the son of John, and I've also been a car brand.*

> This paragraph clues the names of many of the people who have been President in that time:
>
>  '*a whole city*' - George **Washington**, the first President.
>  '*a neighbor*' - OP's intent was Martin **van Buren**, as 'Buren' is Dutch for 'neighbours' (although personally I also enjoyed @SteveV's suggestion of Woodrow **Wilson** in comments, paying homage to Wilson the neighbour in *Home Improvement*!).
>  '*a teddy bear*' - Theodore '**Teddy**' Roosevelt.
>  '*a shrub*' - George **Bush**.
>  '*a field of roses*' - Theodore and Franklin D. **Roosevelt** (again, a Dutch translation of the name).
>  '*a fat cat that likes lasagna*' - James **Garfield**.
>  '*a grant*' - Ulysses S. **Grant**.
>  '*the son of John*' - Andrew and Lyndon B. **Johnson**.
>  '*a car brand*' - Gerald **Ford** (maybe even Abraham **Lincoln** too!).

*Now I've become the notion that I display my superiority over others, which many others considered true of me anyway since the very beginning.*

> The current President is Donald **Trump** - a word whose meaning is similar to having 'superiority over others' (like a *trump suit* in card games...); a word which his rivals might consider appropriate due to his reputation in business...

Comment: @Lucas i would have thought Jvyfba, gur arvtuobe sebz *Ubzr Vzcebirzrag*!